# UrlRewriteFilter outside the context-path

Tags: url-rewriting, oracle-apex

I am trying to use  http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ to map Not Found URLs into new pages. But the problem is that the old urls ,That are indexed in Google, do not have context-path.
e.g:

The old URL: mydomain.com/xxxx 
The new RUL: mydomain.com/apex/f?p=xxx

I was able to map from mydomain.com/apex/xxxx to mydomain.com/apex/yyyyy. But, I need to map any coming request similar to this mydomain.com/xxxx  ( does not have "apex" context-path )
into mydomain.com/apex/f?p=xxx.

How can I do it ? I am using Glassfish open source 3.1.2.2 
Oracle Apex Listener 2